# What is use of hashCode() and equals() method in Java?

Tags: java

I have little problem with java. i am not able to get accurate result.
        what's wrong with this code please help me out from this code
your own objects as keys in Maps or in Sets. To use your own objects as keys in Maps or in Sets.code not executing correctly..

what is use of hashcode and equals in java.

### Code:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Person(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "{ID is: " + id + "; name is: " + name + "}";
    }
}

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //creating person object
        Person p1 = new Person(0, "Bob");
        Person p2 = new Person(1, "Sue");
        Person p3 = new Person(2, "Mike");
        Person p4 = new Person(1, "Sue");

        Map<Person, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Person, Integer>();
        //putting on map
        map.put(p1, 1);
        map.put(p2, 2);
        map.put(p3, 3);
        map.put(p4, 1);

        //displaying the result
        for(Person key: map.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key + ": " + map.get(key));
        }

        //using set
        Set<Person> set = new LinkedHashSet<Person>();

        //adding on set
        set.add(p1);
        set.add(p2);
        set.add(p3);
        set.add(p4);

        //displaying the result
        System.out.println(set);
    }
}
```

### Expected Output:

```
{ID is: 0; name is: Bob}: 1
    {ID is: 1; name is: Sue}: 1
    {ID is: 2; name is: Mike}: 3
    [{ID is: 0; name is: Bob}, {ID is: 1; name is: Sue}, {ID is: 2; name is: Mike}]
```

Comment: You should override hashCode and equals.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods are both implemented in the superclass `Object`.
In real worl applications, you may incounter the need to override both of these methods but don't do unless you understand their utility. I'll try to give the best in short:

**equals()** method is used for equivalence relations.
**hashCode()** is used to provide, as it reveals, a hash code which is a 32-byte representation of the object.

Imagine that you have a class `Person` with below declaration:

```
public class Person {
  public int nationalIdentityNumber;
  public String firstName;
  public String secondName;
  public Person (int nationalIdentityNumber, String firstName, String secondName) {
    this.nationalIdentityNumber = nationalIdentityNumber;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.secondName = secondName;
  }
}
```

When not overriding the `equals()` methods:

```
Person p1 = new Person(1234,"Jhon","Legend");
Person p1 = new Person(1234,"Mary","Richard");
```

When we call `p1.equals(p2)` this will result in a `false` result thus the default method from `Object` class compares the objects references. But what I actually you may need is that two Persons are considered equals when their *nationalIdentityNumber* instance variable is equal so you need to override the `equals()` implementation as below:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
  boolean result = false;
  if (object == null || object.getClass() != getClass()) {
    result = false;
  } else {
    Person person = (Person) object;
    if (this.nationalIdentityNumber == person.nationalIdentityNumber) {
      result = true;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

So `p1.equals(p2)` will now return a true result.

Now back to `hashCode`, imagine you are registering your `Person` objects in a `HashSet`

```
HashSet<Person> personsHS = new HashSet<Person>();
    personsHS.add(p1);
    personsHS.add(p2);
```

When invoquing

```
System.out.println("personsHS.contains( new Person(1234,Jhon,Legend))--->>>"+personsHS.contains(new Person(1234,"Jhon","Legend")));
```

it will result in *personsHS.contains( new Person(1234,"Jhon","Legend"))--->>>false* statement because the HashSet is using the default `Object#hashCode()` method to determine the equality of keys thus we need to override it to ensure the  `Person` uniqueness (based on your requirements) inside the hashtables:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
  return this.nationalIdentityNumber;
}
```

So that

```
System.out.println("personsHS.contains(new Person(1234,Jhon,Legend))--->>>"+personsHS.contains(new Person(1234,"Jhon","Legend")));
```

will result in *personsHS.contains( new Person(1234,"Jhon","Legend"))--->>>true*

This is a simplest that it could be but note that it will always depend on your application and your own objects to wether or not to override this methods and which fashion to do so.

BR.

Answer (score 1):

Cfr the general contract for [hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29):

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then
>   calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce
>   the same integer result.

Answer (score 0):

In java, to use your own objects in some fonctionnalities you sometimes need to create some "generic" fonctions. HashCode and Equals for instance.

To use your objects in a hashmap like you are doing, java needs those. So you have to implement them in your "person" class. Here is an article explaining why in some case we need to override these methods and what exactly they are doing:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.ca/2011/02/how-to-write-equals-method-in-java.html

Normally you can auto-generate them withing your IDE, in NetBeans you can go to: Source - Insert Code - Equals and Hashcode.

Then it should work.

Comment: please elaborate i am not able to understand  >>some "generic" fonctions

Comment: In order to use your person class in an hashMap, Java needs to be able to be able to compare 2 "person" objects. This is done with the methods equals() and hashCode(), hashCode produces a hash and equals() makes a comparaison between 2 hashCode() results of 2 "persons".

In other words: Java need to be able to use these 2 fonctions in your person class in order to make them work in a hashMap, so  you need them. But you can actually auto-generate them in both Eclipse and NetBeans, depending on what you are using.

I used the term generic for these 2 fonctions because they can be auto-generated.

Comment: can i see the how comparion doing in java

Comment: I found you an example similar with your code. This is also a good article explaining why you need to override those functions.

[Here's the link](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ca/2011/02/how-to-write-equals-method-in-java.html)